# Angular Electron - Uncaught Exception

Tags: angular, electron, try-catch, uncaught-exception

So I have this Angular app that I've made for my company with a working web version but they've asked me to make it into a .exe app so I've searched for solutions. That's where I learned about Electron, I installed it and managed to make a .exe of my application but the problem is that there was a part of my code that's not working and it's about a try...catch block that's not working, wether it is here or not I would get a `"Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'y')".`

```
const Client: Client = this.model.LatLongFromFormContent;
    let convertedAddress = await this.provider.search({query: ""+Client.Adresse+","+Client.CP+" "+Client.Ville});
    let latLngClient: any;
    try{
      latLngClient = L.latLng(convertedAddress[0].y, convertedAddress[0].x);
      let closestAgency: string = "";
      let distanceClosestAgency: number = 500;

      AgencyList.forEach(async agency =>{
          let distance = (latLngClient.distanceTo(L.latLng(agency.GPS[0], agency.GPS[1]))/1000);
          if (distance <= distanceClosestAgency){
            closestAgency = agency.Num_agence+" - "+agency.VILLE;
            distanceClosestAgency = distance
          }
      })
      this.model.distanceToClosestAgency = Math.round(distanceClosestAgency *100)/100;
      this.model.closestAgency = closestAgency;
    }catch (error){
      this.model.formGroup.controls['CP'].setErrors({'incorrect': true})
      this.model.formGroup.controls['Ville'].setErrors({'incorrect':true})
    }
```

If the error is caught, we're supposed to have a message appear on screen when a div is set to visible

```
<div *ngIf="model.formGroup.controls['CP'].invalid && model.formGroup.controls['Ville'].invalid && model.formGroup.controls['CP'].value != null" class="mt-2 alert alert-danger">
      Vérifiez que le code postal et la ville correspondent bien.
    </div>
```

but this is not happening, instead I have the error I pointed out earlier...

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Try moving your `let convertedAddress` inside the try catch.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work :(

Comment: Do you use `convertedAddress[0].y` somewhere else perhaps in the template? I don't have problems catching `undefined` inside an electron app's try catch block. On another note you don't have any awaits inside your `forEach` loop, so I don't think that you need an `async` function there. You could check if `convertedAddress[0]` is undefined and then handle the error yourself, return the function and setup the error in your formgroup.

Comment: Nope, this is the only place where I use `convertedAddress[0].y` in the template... And thanks for the advide about the awaits in my loop

Comment: I think you need to either log the contents of `convertedAddress[0]` or attach a `debugger` before creating you latLng. I only see one place where you are calling `.y` referenced from the error, saying that probably your `convertedAddress[0]` is undefined, so you should try to look into what is happening there. But I agree an `undefined` error is strange inside a try catch block. electron should be able to handle that.

Comment: What bothers me is the fact that the try catch block does works when I'm running the app in web version using ng serve...